# Translation of 'une luronne' as tomboy?

Tags: vocabulaire

I've been reading a few historical fiction books set in the Victorian era (the Flashman series). 
There are a few French characters so the authour uses some French words without translation in their speech.
One character describes a female character as 'une luronne' and the description implies that it means she is some kind of tomboy. 
Google translate tells me it means 'buxom dame', which doesn't quite seem to fit.
Can anyone explain this term to me?

---

> "Where did she learn to stalk like that and... so on?"
>  "In the
>   Breton woods as a child, with her three elder brothers." He chuckled.
>   "She was *une luronne*—a tomboy, no? *Oui un garçon manqué*. Six years
>   younger than they, but their match in all sport, running, climbing,
>   shooting... oh, and daring! [...]
>
> [ George MacDonald Fraser, [*Flashman and the Tiger*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TmqBhanqHAoC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22George%20MacDonald%20Fraser%22%20%20tiger&pg=PA194#v=onepage&q=tomboy&f=false), Knopf
>   Doubleday Publishing Group, 2007 ]

Comment: Could you quote the description for us please? I never really heard "une luronne" meaning something close to a tomboy, so I'm curious about the context.

Comment: Google is not a good transaltor, have a look at http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/luronne/?utm_source=reversoweb&utm_medium=textlink&utm_campaign=resultpage

Comment: It took some time to realize it (surely misguided with "tomboy"), but "`un joyeux luron`" is an old expression, `luronne` being the feminine version. I think that apart that old expression and Gai-Luron (old comic of Gotlib) there is no other place where I saw/heard that word.

Comment: usually it describes someone that is joyful

Comment: An experience you can try is [this one](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnrtl.fr%2Fdefinition%2Fluron), but beware this is a(n eerie) translation! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @onvousaouï. I think a good translation in this context is 'Daughter or woman vigorous, bold and sometimes sassy.' from your [link](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnrtl.fr%2Fdefinition%2Fluron)

Answer (score 2):

> Elle a pour se protéger [...] un certain poignard mignon que la
>   luronne porte toujours sur elle dans quelque coin, malgré les
>   ordonnances du prévôt [...]
>
> [ Victor Hugo, [*Notre-Dame de Paris*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6497803t/f52.item.r=luronne), 1831 au TLFi ([luron](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/luron)) ]

On indique que c'est le nom luron au féminin, vieilli ou populaire, qu'on définit comme la « fille ou femme vigoureuse, hardie et parfois délurée » (on trouve aussi historiquement au [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/160828) « femme qui ne s'effarouche pas aisément, de mœurs suspectes ») ; on donne Hugo 1832 comme attestation de l'emploi au féminin (TLFi). À l'origine se rattachant à une série d'emplois populaires basés sur un refrain (v. 1500) :

> Au vau, lure, lurette,
>  Au vau, lure, luron.
>  Mon Dieu, que je
>   suis vray luron.
>
> [ [*La Mère, le Fils et l'Examinateur*](https://books.google.com/books?id=XAXn1kIQ6Y8C&dq=viollet-le-duc%20examinateur&pg=PA374#v=onepage&q=viollet-le-duc%20examinateur&f=false) ds. Ancien théatre
>   françois, éd. Viollet le Duc, t.II, p.374 ]

Avec le sens de *joyeux compère/bon vivant*, l'emploi est souvent qualifié par *joyeux/gai*, et se spécialise ensuite au 19<sup>e</sup> pour *hardi en amour* ; on dit cette valeur est réalisée par le féminin *luronne* (DHLF/Rey).

Comment: Si une question est en anglais, svp, répondez en anglais